# can you get me select statement Modified_Date=Today?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to get all the records using MS SQL SELECT where Modified_Date=Today
my table looks like:

```
created_by          modified_date
20150723081006      2015-07-23 15:14:22.843
20150723081006      2015-09-04 00:14:24.463
20150723081006      2015-09-04 00:14:24.463
```

Answer (score 0):

One simple way to accomplish this would be to cast your modified date as a date value (removing the time portion) and then comparing it to the current date (again, with time removed):

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE CAST(Modified_Date AS DATE) = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That really worked.